# jquery - function being executed multiple times on page scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Need your help guys, so, i have the following code, it recognize if the user scroll down or up, and after that it scroll a editable div down or up. I'm animating the editable div show up and show off, but when i scroll the page is executing the function a lot of times, and this is hampering the animation causing delay. How do I get the function to be executed only once when scrolling occurs?

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
        $("#textarea").animate({'top': '-75' + 'px'}, 500);
    } else {
        $("#textarea").addClass('fixed').animate({'top': '75' + 'px'}, 500);
    };
    position = scroll;
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s92e88Le/

Comment: You may want to look at the scrollstart and scrollstop events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it work with that:

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var isWorking = 0;

    if(scroll > position) {
        $("#textarea").animate({'top': '-25' + 'px'}, 70);
    } else {
        if(isWorking == 0) {
            isWorking = 1;
            $("#textarea").addClass('fixed').animate({
                'top': '75' + 'px'},
                70, function() {
                isWorking = 0;
            });
        }
    };
    position = scroll;
});
```